# vim + iterm: how to use mouse for everything EXCEPT selection?

Tags: user-interface, vim, configuration, mouse, iterm

Ok, have a very specific setup question. I'm using Mac OS X, iTerm, and vim. I really like using my mouse for clicking tabs in normal mode, scrolling in normal mode etc. (e.g. I *already have the mouse working* within iTerm/vim).

However, I dislike using visual mode for selecting. I just want to use OS X selection **not** vim's visual select. The next logical step? Disable visual selection in the `mouse` options:

`set mouse=nicr`

The problem with this is that when I try to select (using the mouse) vim intercepts the mouse click and doesn't allow me to select at all!

Anyone know how deal with this issue? It feels like its solvable if one knew the proper character/control codes (which I obviously do not).

Goal: use the mouse in vim for everything except "select". Let iTerm/OS do the selection.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't have a Mac, but under Linux holding Shift while highlighting allows you to use the mouse to copy with the mouse settings you mentioned.

See the "Note:" in :h mouse

Comment: rson, thanks for you response. On my mac the correct key is alt/option. 

That works perfectly, thanks so much! (It seems so obvious now...)

Comment: Thanks! Now, if only there was a way to block select in iTerm (otherwise you are also selecting line numbers, which is annoying).

Comment: This answer helped me figure out how to send a right-click to an ncurses program (XaoS) running in iTerm2: when using XaoS with the aalib driver on a Macbook, clicking on the trackpad zooms in and SHIFT+two-finger click on the trackpad zooms out! Awesome!

Comment: Thanks. The alt works great. But meanwhile, all my vims work perfectly (fedora, debian, etc) but I can't work with my slackware vim. Weird! -- in fact, set mouse= without options does what I want. I do not use mouse for anything on vim.